# IE8 Rendering as IE7 By Default?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

I just received a new computer at work, with IE8 set to render all sites as IE7. This was a shock to me. Does anyone know if *ALL* installations of IE8 default to IE7 rendering? And if so, is there anything a web developer can do to force IE8 rendering?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I know by default IE8 renders only intranet sites as IE7. To disable this go to Tools -> Compatibility View Settings and uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility view". Also there is a checkbox "Display all sites in Compatibility view" in this dialog - it looks like it's checked for you. It's not standart setting, maybe it is your domain policy.

Anyway, if you need to force IE8 to render pages as IE8 use `X-UA-Compatible` http header. You can add `meta` tag in a `head` section of your page, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#SetMode)

Comment: I've added that tag, but IE8 set to render as IE7 seems to ignore it. Thanks for the tip on intranet sites - and I'm glad to hear that the compatability view isn't a standard setting. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: @Matrym: see "Controlling Default Rendering" section of the article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#Defaults)

Comment: @Matrym: what is an output of "alert(document.documentMode)" javascript?

Comment: I'm with Matrym in this. I'm using "<!doctype html>" and "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> " and my site is STILL identifying as IE7 for css rendering and "7" for documentMode for an Intranet site.

Comment: I ran into this running IE 11, and unchecking said checkbox fixed it for me as well.