# IE8 display inline-block not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Say I have the following code

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
  span, ul, ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }   
</style>
<span>i would want</span>
<ul>
  <li>this</li>
  <li>on</li>
  <li>one line.</li>
</ul>
```

I want this to display inline in IE8. Everywhere I have read everything says this should work, IE8 supports inline-block. However after a morning of trying I cant get the above to line up. I know I could float it, but with the other elements on my page (not shown here) I would need to use a 'clearfix' which is more mark up. I only need to target IE8 and would love to know why inline block doesn't work for me when apparently its supported. The above code does what I want when viewed in Google Chrome.

Comment: Best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703017/ie-display-inline-block

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't declared a doctype. Try placing this on the first line, before the html tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The code you pasted works in IE8 with that doctype.

Comment: I love you, this saved me a lot of IE-ache!

Comment: Woah! Damn I forget this everytime

Comment: @Iazel You meant IE's-hit

Comment: Thank you was worried I'd have to go scouring the web for an answer.

Answer (score 37):

Not all IE8 versions seem to work equally. I found that the given code, even with a DOCTYPE, does not work in IE 8.0.6001.18702, which is an early version.

However, the workaround for lower IE versions did its job on that particular IE 8 as well:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    li { display: inline; }
</style>   
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I only added !important to override, it seems like inline is actually inline-block in IE. Thank You!

Comment: Randomly stumbled across this, worked for me, inline is indeed inline-block. Thanks

Comment: Cool, this worked for me, I have the same problem, Windows 7 IE 8 and inline-block does not work

Comment: Exactly, the same for me! I have exactly the same version of IE and the DOCTYPE itself doesn't work.

Comment: and please note that inline-block is supported by IE for inline elements - span, em, ... without these problems. Look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16462251/684229

Comment: This only happens when IE8 is in Compatibility View, which is an IE7 emulation. It's not a problem of differing IE8 versions, but a problem of improper rendering modes. It's not surprising that this should happen even if a DOCTYPE is used since IE7 and earlier have always had this problem even if a DOCTYPE was used anyway. Furthermore, 8.0.6001.18702 is the RTM, not an early version, and even that isn't relevant because `display: inline-block` support was already complete starting from the first beta. The correct solution to this is `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Answer (score 18):

You can set margin-right:1px

worked for me pretty well.

Comment: This is by far the best option out of all the answers. Great tip!

Comment: removed the broken link (http://www.compsoft.co.uk/Blog/2009/11/inline-block-not-quite-inline-blocking.html) They seem to change their website and cannot find the post anymore.

Comment: [Web archive for the rescue](http://web.archive.org/web/20120224235209/http://www.compsoft.co.uk/Blog/2009/11/inline-block-not-quite-inline-blocking.html)

Comment: Don't you just love IE :-/

Answer (score 13):

In my experience it is always a better idea to use the universal way (IE6+) of declaring an inline block. Even if you are targeting newer browsers every time I've tried to say that it's only supported by newer browsers some client still messes with their document type, and then the sales say, it needs to be fixed, because clients can still see it and does not get it, that it's down to their IE settings and not our fault. More over when you are using inline-blocks for structural stuff, it keeps the site from completely disintegrating if the user is viewing the site on an older IE for what ever reason.

```
display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

Comment: This is idiomatic! Just like `if (var i < 0; i y x.length; i++)`

Comment: @HerrSerker Don't know what you mean by that, but this is how you get inline-block in a IE6+ manner (like it or not).

Comment: Yes, exactely what I mean. You should learn it as you learn the JS loop construct.

Comment: “Idiomatic”, yet you wrote `if` instead of `for`… @HerrSerker

Comment: There seems to be an error in the formula, the right one is: `display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
display: inline;` without a second "*".

Comment: @Marcus the problem there is you are overwriting the display to pure inline. It should still work in IE7-, but every were else it should be simply inline. The `*` part is a IE7- hack i.e. this CSS property will be applied to only IE6 & IE7, but if you leave it out then it's read by all browsers making the element into a inline element and not a inline-block. If you wanted to you could leave the `*` on the `zoom: 1.0;` because the zoom is 1.0 anyway so if you reset it to 1.0 it does not matter.

Comment: Yeah you were right, the second "*" doesn't matter, so therefore +1 ;)

Comment: I use `display: inline; display: inline-block; *zoom: 1;` -- IE will ignore the second display rule and zoom will only apply to older IE

Answer (score 9):

IE8 will treat it as a block level element unless you use float.

```
.divInlineBlock
{
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that IE8 will act like IE7 if you are viewing an intranet site, which can happen as you develop! See this StackOverflow question:

[IE8 Rendering as IE7 By Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457851/ie8-rendering-as-ie7-by-default)

Answer (score 3):

For IE8 - you can add a specific declaration:

`display: inline-table;`

which works great.