# IE8 css ssues menubar not displayed proerly

Tags: css, internet-explorer

below is the css script for menu of [this site](http://softwareservicesindia.com/Pradnnya_blog/wordpress_site/?page_id=1290)

```
 #navmenu{
 z-index:99999;
 margin-top:40px;
 margin-left:400px;
 position:absolute;
 }

 #navMenu li {
 float:left;
 color:#ececec;
 list-style-type:none;
 }

 #navMenu ul {
 margin-left:300px;
 margin-top:70px;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#000000;
 }


 #navMenu li a{
 width:70px;
 height:15px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight:700;
 float:left;
 color:#707070;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 text-decoration: none;display: block;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-image: url(img/image_menubutton.JPG);
 border-right:1px solid white;
 margin-right:12px;
 font-family:"Georgia",Georgia,Serif;
 font-weight:900;
 font-size:19px;
 text-align: center;

 }
 #navmenu li.item1{background-image: url(img/about.JPG);}
```

the menu is displayed perfectly in chrome and  FF .But in IE its not proper..

what is the solution to get it displayed properly in IE??

**Edit1**
This is how  the menu looks in IE8

[image]

This is how menu looks in FF

[image]

Comment: And "not proper" means.. what?

Comment: hi ain Fellowman i have edited the question

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >` This is probably why you have the same problem in IE8 and IE9. And you have to `display` settings, one `inline-block`, and later a `block`. And is `#navmenu` and `#navMenu` the same?

Comment: hey thanks..you mean i have to delete <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" > from the code right?and what about blocks can you explain more on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your doctype to make sure IE is understanding `inline-block`

[IE8 display inline-block not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working)

Comment: Looking at your CSS again, I see three `display` properties for the `#navMenu li a`. I'd suggest going back through your CSS and do some major clean up first.

Comment: You're also using `float: left` and `display: inline-block`. Why?

Comment: coz on some site regarding IE css issue i found it that way..

if its not correct then how it should be?

Comment: Well, there is no 'one correct' way. I'm just saying your CSS is a bit messy at this point. I'd suggest cleaning it up and get it working in valid browsers. Then see what's broken in IE and post that as a new question.