# Float left <li>s, but keep the alignment

Tags: css

Id like to keep the `<li>`s aligned evenly at the top, here's my CSS:

```
ul {
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:510px; 
}

li {
   width:230px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   padding:5px;
   float:left;
   margin:5px 5px 0 0;  
}
```

Here is [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/t6tML/).

Any way to align the top of the `<li>`s evenly?
Here is a picture of what I would like it to be:
[image: Example layout]

Comment: What do you mean keep them aligned evenly?  It looks even to me.

Comment: In other words, keep the boxed aligned to the top, not bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `float`, use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`

http://jsfiddle.net/t6tML/11/

Comment: It starts to get tricky on IE7 and before https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

Comment: Inline-block works fine in IE8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block. Also, please note in your question next time that you need code which works in IE8.

Comment: If you have problem with IE8 have a look at here: [ie8 display inline-block not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working)

Comment: This is my DOCTYPE, <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> and it's not working on my end.

Comment: Do you must use that DOCTYPE?

Comment: Try with html5 DOCTYPE. Like this `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: That does not work either, display-inline only works with tags that are natively inline such as spans. I replaced LIs with SPANS and replaced UL with a DIV. It it now works in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the ul needs to equal the combined width of the li elements:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 1482px;
}
```

Each of your li elements has a width of 230px, 5px horizontal margin, 10px horizontal padding, and 2px horizontal border so:

230 + 5 + 10 + 2 = 247px

247 * 6 li elements = 1482px

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/t6tML/3/

Comment: Yes, but I need the width to be 510px and I need the boxes to stack.

Comment: Not like Pinterest, I don't want the boxes to merge into each other.

Comment: You want them along the left side?