# Inline-block element inside link: strange behavior in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have an inline-block "circle" element inside `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="#" id="map-start-photo-link" class="map-link start">
    фотогалерея
    <span class="circle"></span>
</a>
```

The behavior is fine in Chrome - hovering and clicking works good. But in IE8 only circles' borders seems to count as link: clicking and hovering in the inner area doesn't work.

here's the project (circles are square in IE8, but it's ok):
http://coob.bitbucket.org/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working and also border-radius wont work in IE8

Comment: @VivekVikranth, none of the solutions works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess with z-indexes. I've set z-indexes for header, footer, draggable map and links  explicitly (and with positive numbers, just in case) and now it works in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Apply CSS property `display: inline-block;` to span.

Comment: Good one Nice approach

Comment: seems like it's already there. what span are you talking about?

Comment: I think its the position: absolute; on both <a> and <span> tags - try giving a <a> a lower z-index and <span> a greater z-index. that must fix it.

Comment: @user3404794, nope, it's not working. it's really funny that spans reacts on border hovers and clicks