# Max-width image and inline-block causes image not to show in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Weird one... if you specify max-width of 100% on an image and display inline-block on its container, combined with a width attribute in the markup, IE8 does not show the image.

Here is a pen: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/pen/MYadRO
(View in full page on IE8: http://codepen.io/iamkeir/full/MYadRO)

```
<div class="problem">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/320x240" width="240" />
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  div {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

It can be fixed by making the container display inline instead of inline-block just for IE8, or specifying a width of 100% and max-width instead of width attribute... but this is not as handy as specifying widths in markup.

Two questions:
1) Is there a better/alternative fix?
2) Any idea *what* is actually going on? (I know, I know, "because IE8".)

NOTE: It seems whilst http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block implies IE8 supports inline-block (), there is a known issue reported in the footer. Should probably be marked as partial support instead:
http://blog.caplin.com/2013/06/07/developing-for-ie8-inline-block-resize-bug/

Comment: Microsoft doesn't support or update IE8 anymore. Neither should we ;).

Comment: Microsoft *does* support IE8 (it also supports IE6 and IE7), just not on Windows XP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110646/ie8-display-inline-block-not-working

Comment: No, doctype is all good.

Comment: It looks fine to me in IE8 and IE7 (doc mode).

Comment: Oh, I would be dancing naked in the streets if we could simply say "We don't have to support IE8". Truth is, we support what a significant percentage of our users use. If several thousand customers a month use IE8 on WinXP, we support IE8 on WinXP or lose those customers (or in our case, get slapped on the hand by our Federal overlords).

Comment: @JamieBarker Sadly, most projects we work on are not up to us to decide which browsers are supported. Its usually up to the client and their requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to give the with to it then you can specify the min-with.

It works if you give min-width:240px; or waht ever width you want to specify.

I Hope it helps